# How to show components conditionally based on route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router for my application. I would like to not show a component when a specific route is acitve i.e. the component is a tab bar which is visible at any place in the component, but I would like to not show it in a specific route. How do I achieve this? Here is my code.

```js
function App() {  
  
  return (
    <Provider store={store} >
       <BrowserRouter forceRefresh={false}>
         <LastLocationProvider>
         <div className="App"> 
            <div className="sidebar-division">
              <Sidebar />
            </div>
                
                  <div className="route-area">
                  <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Homefeed} />
                    <Route path="/account" component={AccountProfile} />
                    <Route exact path={profilelink} component={ProfileComponent} />
                    <Route path={'/:postlink'} component={PostComponent} />
                    <Route exact path="/explore" component={ExploreComponent} />
                    <Route path="/activity" component={ActivityComponent} />
                    <Route path="/library" component={LibraryComponent} />
                  </Switch>
                    <div className="phone-tab-bar-division">
                      <Phonetabbar />
                    </div>
                    </div>
                
                    <ExploreSidebar />
                  
          </div>
         </LastLocationProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

I would like to hide  when the Route

```
<Route path={'/:postlink'} component={PostComponent} />
```

is active.

An example of the Url of the above route is:

```
http://localhost:3000/prvnngrj/p/the-bowhead-whale-population-rebounds-as-the-arctic-water-warms-VuzEblndkT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get access to the URL using `props.history.location.pathname` 
like this

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'

function App(props) {
   const pathname = props.history.location.pathname
}
export default withRouter(App)
```

or you can use `useHistory` hook like this

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom' 
function App() {
   const history = useHistory()
   let pathname = history.location.pathname
}
```

Comment: The url is a variable one, like the format is https://localhostl:300/ *variable* /p/*variable*. What if that is the case

Comment: Do you mean the params? if so then you can access the params with the useParams hook just like useHistory and also props.history gives you everything you need to know about url including the params

Comment: But useParams only works when its called inside a child of the route, I'm trying to hide a tab-bar navigation that is in a much higher order than the place im calling it. How do i proceed with that ?

Comment: The first method using react-router worked perfectly, I just tried it out now !

Comment: glad that i helped